# Laravel : Postgres not pointing to the correct database after macos upgrade

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-valet, valet

After an update of mac os, I having an error from Postgres :

> FATAL:  database "" does not exist.

It's not pointing to the correct database anymore.

I suspect this error to be due to Valet, but reinstalling it doesn't fix the issue.

Any idea ?